# important: call method in dif. javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i need answer of this question as soon as possible

i have 2 script tags in the same page, 2 with the same methods name
and i have a timer

on specific time i want to enable script1 with all method inside it to process
and in another time to enable all methods in script2

i am using every script to draw dif. thing in canvas.

example (psedo code):

```
<script1>
init(){
canvas.draw();
}
</script1>
<script2>
init(){
canvas.draw();
}
</script2>

<canvas>
```

i cant change method name ... how to call init from scrip1 or script2
or
how to snable script1 to call every thing from it then enable script2 to call every thing from it.

Comment: What can you change? can you wrap the init function in another function? can you change the scripts at all? Can you dynamically insert or remove the script tag? A solution would be to remove the script tags from the DOM and insert the one you want back in. This will involve giving them id's or knowing what order they come in

Comment: your question is bit confusing and Irritating(sorry to say). please be clear, while asking a question...

Answer (score 1):

Both script tags will create script code in the same scope, so the second definition of init() will overwrite the first one.  So without renaming them it's not going to work the way you want.

If you do rename one of them then you can just call it.  Since they're in the same scope there's no actual "script1" and "script2" separation.  Any methods/variables defined in one can be seen by the other.